# How to automate iPhone device setting using see Test?

Tags: appium-ios, seetest

I am trying to open ios mobile app using see test, for that I need to change iPhone device setting but I don't have idea how to open device setting.

Please suggest me how to open iPhone device setting using seeTest?

Comment: Did you search in web before asking this question in SO? Is it a programming related question?

Comment: Yes it is a programming related. I write script in java using tool see test   and testNG for ios automation. I searched in google but not getting proper answer for see test. Few answers I got using Appium and I have tried same with see test too but not able to get open iPhone device setting.

If you have any solution for the same please suggest me.